# Writing to package.json in a Project using Jenkins and Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, package.json, jenkins-groovy

I want to change the **version** value in the **package.json** file, but I am getting the following error. I can read the **version** but I get the following error while changing **version** value.
How can i solve it.

```
org.kohsuke.stapler.NoStaplerConstructorException: There's no @DataBoundConstructor on any constructor of class java.lang.String
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.ClassDescriptor.loadConstructorParamNames(ClassDescriptor.java:288)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.<init>(DescribableModel.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:474)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.injectSetters(DescribableModel.java:429)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:331)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:305)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {file={name=demo, version=0.0.0-alpha.0, dependencies={@testing-library/jest-dom=^5.16.5, @testing-library/react=^13.4.0, @testing-library/user-event=^13.5.0, react=^18.2.0, react-dom=^18.2.0, react-scripts=5.0.1, web-vitals=^2.1.4}, scripts={start=react-scripts start, build=react-scripts build, test=react-scripts test, eject=react-scripts eject, sonar-scanner=node_modules/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner}, eslintConfig={extends=[react-app, react-app/jest]}, browserslist={production=[>0.2%, not dead, not op_mini all], development=[last 1 chrome version, last 1 firefox version, last 1 safari version]}, description=## Available Scripts, main=index.js, repository={type=git, url=git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/***.git}, keywords=[**, Demo, UI], publishConfig={registry=http://****/repository/npm-private/}}} for org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.json.WriteJSONStep
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:334)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:305)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:124)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
```

- 

**code in groovy file:**

```
def updateProjectPackage(params) {
    packageFile = readJSON(file: 'package.json')
    //params.appVersion = 0.0.0-alpha.0
    packageFile.version = params.appVersion
    writeJSON file: packageFile
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `writeJSON` part seems wrong. It should be something like this.

```
writeJSON file: 'package.json', json: packageFile
```

Comment: It worked when I tried it this way. Thank you